# Append to json_encode pho

Tags: php

I am trying to append to json data but its not working its just briing back an empty result file saw that you just appended to the out put of jsoneconde but maybee i am doing it wrong.

// we just want to use simple php json encode here no need to over complicated.

```
public function generate_json($table_data)
{
    if($table_data)
    {            
       $table_data= $this->get_property_gallery_data($table_data);
       return json_encode($table_data);
    }

 }
/**
 * Function to get the table data for the items of a property
 * @author David Buckley
 */


public  function get_property_gallery_data($property_id)
{
      $where = $this->get_query_where();
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `#__{$this->items_table}` WHERE 1 " . $where;         
      $galleries = wpl_db::select($query, 'loadObjectList');        

      return $galleries;

}
```

Comment: Your question isn't much clear. I suggest you to check function inputs once again.

Comment: Try breaking down your code to see which part is going wrong. There's a lot going on here so it's hard to say where your problem lies.

Comment: The question is very vague. Make sure to correct the typos and mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the parameter `$property_id` in your method `get_property_gallery_data`.

I don't really understand what you're trying to do here, but I'd imagine that you don't get the correct data from `get_property_gallery_data` if you don't select the correct property. Therefore `json_encode` will have nothing to encode.

Answer (score 0):

You are define $property_id but not used. If you don't need to this variable, kindly removed or change your methods accordingly like this:

```
/**
 * Function to get the table data for the items of a property
 * @author David Buckley
 */
 public  function get_property_gallery_data()
 {
  $where = $this->get_query_where();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `#__{$this->items_table}` WHERE 1 " . $where;         
  $galleries = wpl_db::select($query, 'loadObjectList');        

  return $galleries;
 }



 public function generate_json()
 {
   $table_data= $this->get_property_gallery_data();
   if($table_data) {
      return json_encode($table_data);
   }else{
      return null;
 }
```

If you are still unable to get data, kindly check your get_property_gallery_data() method because if get_property_gallery_data() return value then you will sure get json data but if this method will return null then you can't. So check your method get_property_gallery_data() logic accordingly.